# Trouble with looping and conditionals in C

Tags: c

**EDIT2**: Fixed it myself by replacing `answer = getchar();` on line 38 and 56 with `scanf("%d", &answer);` and it fixed itself, but I don't know why.

Fixed version:

```
Do you order Fish? (Y/N): g
Please enter Y or N only: g
Please enter Y or N only: g
Please enter Y or N only: g
Please enter Y or N only: y
Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut): x
Please enter K or T only: x
Please enter K or T only: x
Please enter K or T only: x
Please enter K or T only: k
What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): x
Please enter S, M, or L only: x
Please enter S, M, or L only: x
Please enter S, M, or L only: x
Please enter S, M, or L only: l
How many orders do you want? (>=0): 2
```

**EDIT**:

full source in case you want to compile and see what's up:  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=83y0SLHQ

okay so everything below actually works, that's fine, now there is a new problem:

**OUTPUT**:

```
Do you order Fish? (Y/N): y
Please enter Y or N only: n
Fish choice (K- Haddock, T- Halibut): s
Please enter K or T only: K
What size (L - Large, M - Medium, S - Small): x
Please enter S, M, or L only: L
How many orders do you want? (>=0): 2
```

**PROBLEM**: notice how if I enter `y` as an option, it tells me to enter Y or N again even though it is valid? It shouldn't do that. All other loops work except the first one with the (Y/N).

I did some debugging, and I printed the value of `rc` after the first line and its ASCII value is `10`, so that means my `answer` value is actually reading in `\n` and then only after a second prompt, it reads in the correct ASCII value of `y` and makes the comparison.

Why is it taking in `\n` first?

### **OLD POST**

I have a program where I have to verify the users input. If the user inputs say "y", "Y", "n", or "N", they pass the validation. If they enter anything but that, the program outputs:

`please enter Y or N only`.

I made a `verify` function for this. Values are passed to it like so:

If I want it to only verify characters YNyn, I would do:

`verify("YNyn", 2);`

YNyn are the characters I want to verify, 2 is the number of uppercase characters.

In my verify function, I see if my second parameter is equal to 2 or 3. (it would be 3 if I had `verify("SMLsml", 3);` the SML being small medium large).

I added in `printf` to see what the ASCII values of the first parameter in my verify function were, and they all corresponded correctly.

**OUTPUT**: this means that Y is 89, N is 78, y is 121, n is 110. Value after the - is value I entered (the Y). -1 is the value of variable `rc`.

```
Do you order Fish? (Y/N): Y

Y:89 N:78 y:121 n:110 - answer:89 rc:-1
```

**PROBLEM**: if statements dont validate so rc is not set to 1.

```
if ((answer == validAnswers[0])
 || (answer == validAnswers[1])
 || (answer == validAnswers[2])
 || (answer == validAnswers[3]))
  { rc = 1; }
```

I also tried:

```
if (answer == validAnswers[0]
|| answer == validAnswers[1]
|| answer == validAnswers[2]
|| answer == validAnswers[3]) {rc = -1 }
```

but to no avail, I've tried reformatting the if statement into one line as well, didn't work.

This means that if the value I entered corresponds to the ASCII value of Y, N, y, or n, then variable `rc` should be set to 1. Unfortunately it does not do this, the problem lies within the if statement.

As you can see above, in `89 78 121 110 - 89 -1`, the last value (variable `rc`), the value is -1. This means that my if statements are omitted. Why are they omitted and not setting rc to -1?

**VERIFY FUNCTION**

```
int verifyLoop(char *validAnswers, int numChars) {

    int answer, rc = -1;

    if (numChars == 2) {

    answer = getchar();

        do {printf("\n%d %d %d %d - %d %d\n", validAnswers[0],validAnswers[1],validAnswers[2],validAnswers[3], answer, rc);
            answer = getchar();
            if ((answer == validAnswers[0])
             || (answer == validAnswers[1])
             || (answer == validAnswers[2])
             || (answer == validAnswers[3]))
            { rc = 1; }
            if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
            {
                printf("Please enter %c or %c only: ", validAnswers[0], validAnswers[1]);
                while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                    answer = getchar();
            } 
        } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
    }
    else if (numChars == 3) {

    answer = getchar();

        do {printf("\n%d %d %d %d %d %d - %d\n", validAnswers[0],validAnswers[1],validAnswers[2],validAnswers[3],validAnswers[4],validAnswers[5], answer);
            answer = getchar();
            if (answer == validAnswers[0] 
             || answer == validAnswers[1] 
             || answer == validAnswers[2]
             || answer == validAnswers[3]
             || answer == validAnswers[4]
             || answer == validAnswers[5])
            { rc = 1; }
            if (rc == -1 && answer != -1) 
            {
                printf("Please enter %c, %c, or %c only: ", validAnswers[0], validAnswers[1], validAnswers[2]);
                while (answer != -1 && answer != '\n')
                    answer = getchar();
            } 
        } while (rc == -1 && answer != -1);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for doing at least some debugging before asking the question (that seems to be a very rare trait on Stack Overflow).  But you should continue down that track; add more print statements (e.g. what is the value of `answer`?).

Comment: Yeah I did that, the value of answer corresponds to one of the values of validAnswer[], so therefore it SHOULD set rc to 1, and if rc is 1, then the error message of `please enter x` is omitted, and it goes to the next prompt.

Comment: One more hint: this is related to getchar()

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: A supposition: folks do debug -- I hope they do, anyway -- but neglect to post the results; which is interesting. Anyway, this is off-topic. I will cease and desist from meta-discussing in comments to a confused user's question.

Comment: Oh wow true, okay I changed it and it does show 1 now which is good. Now I need to see why it hangs on a second statement and doesn't proceed.

Comment: If you'd like to simplify and generalize the operation of looking for one character inside a string, take a look at the `strchr()` function.

Comment: That is because of your first getChar() call (before the loops starts) which eats your correct answer and leaves a newline.  Just get rid of it and it will solve that problem.

Comment: @inafziger - Did that, now I get an even weirder output so that's no good.

Comment: really?  You removed the one here:  `if (numChars == 2) {

    answer = getchar();`?

Comment: Yes sir and that messes it up, but now I replaced that `answer = getchar();` with `scanf("%d", &answer);` and everything is dandy.

Comment: This question is a mess. Where is the question and where is the answer? It's now a bunch of edits and it's hard to tell what goes where. Please fix it.

Comment: Go away Lightness, not sure why you decided to necro my posts and comment on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that it reports -1 and continues with no errors is because it is actually working.  :)

However, it reports -1 because your printf is at the top of the loop, and prints the value **before** the if statement and the setting of rc to 1.

Move your `printf` to **just above** the end of the loop to see the correct values.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it! Now there is another problem -_-

Answer (score -1):

There is a getchar after the print, then you are not comparing with the value of the first getchar, but from the second one.